# How can i convert docx to markdown in Python

Tags: parsing, ms-word, markdown

I'm trying to convert docx files to markdown for my LLM project. When i try pandoc or other libs i can't convert tables properly. What's your solution?

I tried pandoc, word's offical library and many other things.

Do you have any suggestion for that or maybe another method?